# Как обратиться в Firebase Database из сервиса FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase-android

Приложение работает с Firabase DataBase нормально. Функция FireBase отправляет оповещение, которое ловит `FirebaseMessagingService`.

```
public class GetFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DATA");
        db.keepSynced(true);

        db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(....){} // читаем данные.
        .......
```

Так вот, если запущена основная активность, все работает.
Если же нет, и оповещение приходит, когда приложение выгружено 
из списка запущенных, то вылетает с ошибкой на строчке

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DATA");
```

ошибка:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

любое направление где искать, любые идеи. А то два дня поисков уже ...

Comment: А какие данные вы получаете в `onMessageReceived` из базы, и что с ними делаете?

Comment: Эти строчки намерено опущены тк не участвуют в ошибке (их можно из кода вообще убрать). Отправляется информация об изменении в определенной ветке БД (название ветки), и далее нужно эти изменения прочитать. В коде название заменено ("DATA"), что не влияет на результат. И выводится оповещение об изменении, но до этого код вообще не доходит.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено самостоятельно. После чтения документации и ряда экспериментов:

Из сервиса, который должен работать нужно вызвать метод public static, который находится в основной активити (может не основную тоже можно использовать, не проверяли, но важно что это активити).

Из сервиса:

```
MainActivity.getLoopFromActivity();
```

А уже все действо идет в этом методе, который помещаем в MainActyvity:

```
    public static void getLoopFromActivity(){

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());  // берем loop основного потока
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // тут делаем все что нужно

          db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DATA");
          db.keepSynced(true);

          db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(....){} // читаем данные.
           .......
       }
    });
}
```

Ошибка пропала. Работает как с активным activity, так и когда его нет в списке.
Может кому и пригодится.