# Как в firebaseDatabase добавить элемент из FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-database

помогите мне понять почему из FirebaseMessagingService не получается добавить элемент в Firebase RealTimeDatabase!

[Эта статья не помогла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879570/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-firebase-database-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-firebasemessagingservice)

Код из MesseginService:

```
    package app.beer.mailboxeset.services

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager
import app.beer.mailboxeset.MESSAGE_RECEIVED_ACTION
import app.beer.mailboxeset.MainActivity
import app.beer.mailboxeset.NotificationsBroadcastReceiver
import app.beer.mailboxeset.R
import app.beer.mailboxeset.database.Database
import app.beer.mailboxeset.model.Notification
import app.beer.mailboxeset.utils.*
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

const val FCM_CHANNEL_ID = "MAIL_BOXES_ET_FCM_CHANNEL_ID"
const val FCM_GROUP_ID = "MAIL_BOXES_ET_FCM_GROUP"

const val BR_TITLE = "title"
const val BR_BODY = "body"
const val BR_PHOTO = "photoUrl"

class MessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
        buildNotification(message)
        MainActivity.getLoopFromActivity(
            message.notification?.title.toString(),
            message.notification?.body.toString(),
            message.notification?.imageUrl.toString()
        )
    }

    private fun buildNotification(message: RemoteMessage) {
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                FCM_CHANNEL_ID,
                "Главный каннал уведомлений",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            channel.description =
                "Этот канал уведомлений нужен чтобы оповещать вас о событиях в нашем приложений"
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

            NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, FCM_CHANNEL_ID)
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext)
        }

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString(BR_TITLE, message.notification?.title.toString())
        bundle.putString(BR_BODY, message.notification?.body.toString())
        bundle.putString(BR_PHOTO, message.notification?.imageUrl.toString())

        val intentM = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intentM.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        intentM.putExtra("open_notifications", true)
        intentM.putExtra("notification", bundle)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext,
            124,
            intentM,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        )

        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setGroup(FCM_GROUP_ID)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(message.notification?.title)
            .setContentText(message.notification?.body)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)

        if (message.notification?.imageUrl != null)
            builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(message.notification!!.imageUrl.toString()))

        manager.notify(0, builder.build())
    }

}
```

Код из MainActivity где должен добавится элемент:

```
companion object {
    fun getLoopFromActivity(title: String, body: String, photoUrl: String?) {
//            val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())  // берем loop основного потока
//            handler.post {
//                val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
//                    .child(NODE_NOTIFICATIONS)
//                ref.keepSynced(true)
//
//                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
//                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
//
//                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
//                        if (!snapshot.hasChild(title)) {
//                            val data = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
//                            data[CHILD_NOT_TITLE] = title
//                            data[CHILD_NOT_BODY] = body
//                            data[CHILD_NOT_PHOTO] = photoUrl.toString()
//
//                            REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_NOTIFICATIONS)
//                                .child(title)
//                                .updateChildren(data)
//                        }
//                    }
//                })
//            }
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            .child(NODE_NOTIFICATIONS)
        ref.keepSynced(true)

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasChild(title)) {
                    val data = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                    data[CHILD_NOT_TITLE] = title
                    data[CHILD_NOT_BODY] = body
                    data[CHILD_NOT_PHOTO] = photoUrl.toString()

                    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_NOTIFICATIONS)
                        .child(title)
                        .updateChildren(data)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в коде не видно попытки что-то записать, только прочитать. Скорее всего в этом дело.

Comment: там есть в коде где написано "Код из MainActivity где должен добавится элемент" там считывается смотрится если записи уже с таким названием или нет, если нет то записываем

Comment: А как вы проверяете что код исполняется и данные не добавляются? Пробовали выводить что-то в логи на всех этапах? Например перед и после записи данных? В теории вы могли не попасть в максимальный промежуток времени, который доступен сервису на обработку сообщения. Коли так, то код не будет до конца исполнен. В этом случае надо или отдельный севрис запускать или использовать WorkManager для исполнения длительных операций, особенно, если они требуют сетевого соединения, которое может быть долгим из-за низкой скорости соединения..

Comment: В логи я выводил, смотрел, когда приложение работает все нормально добавляется, а когда в background'е приложение ничего не добавляется

Comment: попробую сделать через workManager

Comment: Кажется я понял в чём у вас проблема. Вы отправляете `notification` уведомление, которое при запущенном приложении приходит в onMessageReceived, а когда приложение в фоне - то onMessageReceived просто не вызывается. Т.е. ваш вопрос, по идее, не про запись в базу при приходе пуша, а про то, почему onMessageReceived не вызывается, когда приложение в фоне. Тут поможет отправка `data` пушей, без секции `notification` - в этом случае все пуши будут приходить в onMessageReceived в любом состоянии приложения (если оно не ForceStop-нуто, конечно - тогда вообще ничего работать не будет)

Comment: А что это за data пуши?

Comment: Это пуши, где только `data` объект есть в JSON инет `notification` объекта. Об этом в доке написано тут: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en

Comment: А как тогда отправить data пуш?

Comment: А как вы отправляете пуш сейчас? По идее у вас должен быть backend и с него либо вручную надо дёргать сервер или использовать Admin SDK для отправки пушей.

Comment: Я отправляю через console в clound messaging

Comment: Этот способ в реальной жизни подойдёт либо только для тестов, либо потребует  отдельной программной обратоки клика на пуш - только так можно будет на него прореагировать для совершения какого-то действия. Так что вам надо или сервак поднимать для отправки data пушей или использовать cloudfunctions для этого (очень не советую - мороки много и можно на большие деньги влететь при превышении лимитов случайно при тестах). Либо отказываться от логики совершения действий при приходе пуша и как-то иначе делать то, что вы хотите. Правильный способ - поднимать свой сервак и с него data пуши слать.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо!